# Why doesnt it post to the endpoint I specified in the form

Tags: wordpress

I am trying create my custom admin page without using the Setting Api. Below is a code snippet represent I am trying to do.

```
     <?php 
        $my_nonce = wp_create_nonce('my_plugin_nonce');
     ?>
     <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <!-- Security info -->
        <input type="hidden" name="option_page" value="my_option_group">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update">
        <input type="hidden" id="_my_nonce" name="_my_nonce" value="{$my_nonce}">
        <input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my_option">

        <!-- Post request contents -->               
        <input type="text" name="my_plug_id" value="my plugin id">
        <input type="text" name="my_plug_name" value="my plugin name">

        <!-- Submit button -->      
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save Changes">
     </form>
```

When I submit the form, at the endpoint, it tells me "The link you followed has expired."

From what I understand, there is no link/session create even though I have created and used the nonce.

Can anyone give me some guidance?

Thanks you.

Comment: Why are you trying not to use Settings API? If you don’t want to use Settings API, then you can’t use endpoints from that API as well.

Comment: In that case, is there a way to put my own nonce during the registration of the settings?

Comment: And to answer your question, php markup are too verbose, I would like to create the admin page's interface using the one of the JavaScript frames such as Angular, React, or Vue.

Comment: Don’t do that... WP has its own framework and standards. Building your own solutions ignoring these standards is always a bad idea and is considered a bad practice. It will confuse users too.

Comment: So is there a way to attach my custom nonce during the setting registration?

Comment: And why do you need that nonce? Setting forms already have nonce in them... And yes - of course you can add your own html in these forms (including own nonces)

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. What you see on the example is already a custom created form with my custom nonce. And, granted, the form wont work because the nonce was not part of that option_group/option during registration ( i am assuming it is during registration of the settings ).

So, I would like to ask it is possible make a custom nonce be part of the option_group/option? And, how could i achieve it? If you'd be kind, please provide an example. Thanks.

Comment: Man, it won’t work. Settings API will save only settings that are registered. You can’t create your own, custom form, not register any settings and use options.php as POST request processor... Your fields are not registered as settings, so they won’t get saved...

Comment: Could you provide an example of you meant?